# tf listener cant look up transform frame

Tags: ros, tf-listener

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run `tf tf_echo /Pioneer3AT/map /Pioneer3AT/base_link` and compute exact data needed (so, everything is looking good so far):

```
...
At time 1407419581.729
- Translation: [-8.999, -22.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.000, 0.850. 0.526]
             in RPY [0.000. -0.000, 2.034]
...
```

Working through the tutorials I come up with the following script for a tf listener:

```
import roslib
import rospy
import tf
import sys, traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_P3AT')
    listener = tf.TransformListener()
    rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)

try:
    now = rospy.Time(0)
    (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "/Pioneer3AT/base_link", now)
except:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)​
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/ros/hydro/catkin/src/ros-pioneer3at/scripts/tf_listener.py", Line 15, in <module> (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "/Pioneer3AT/base_link", now) LookupException: "Pioneer3AT/map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist
```

Have also tried the following bit of code using the tf and time tutorial:

```
import roslib
import rospy
import tf
import sys, traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_P3AT')
    listener = tf.TransformListener()
    listener.waitForTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "Pioneer3AT/base_link", rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(4.0)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)

try:
    now = rospy.Time.now()
    listener.waitForTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "Pioneer3AT/base_link", now, rospy.Duration(4.0)
    (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "/Pioneer3AT/base_link", now)
except:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)​
```

This throws the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/ros/hydro/catkin/src/ros-pioneer3at/scripts/tf_listener.py", line 16, in  lisener.waitForTransform("/Pioneer3AT/map", "/Pioneer3AT/base_link", now, rospy.Duration(4.0)) Exception: lookup would require extrapolation into the past. Requested time 1407508275.045120001 but the earliest data is at time 1407508275.084692717, when looking up transform from frame [Pioneer3AT/base_link] to frame [Pioneer3AT/map]

Anyone have tips on where to start next?

**edit 1:**

Output from roswtf produces:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
```

## No package or stack in context

Static checks summary:

## No errors or warnings

Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:

- /nodelet_manager:

  - /Pioneer3AT/ps3joy/cmd_vel
- /Pioneer3AT_gmapping:

  - /Pioneer3AT/laserscan
  - /tf_static
- /Pioneer3AT_move_base:

  - /Pioneer3AT/move_base_simple/goal
  - /tf_static

**edit 2:**

Image result of `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree`

Here is an online link of pic:
[link text](http://postimg.org/image/pw5zno2y1/09c69eda/)
and here
[link text](http://postimg.org/image/x051z8cn9/af4573f9/)

**edit 3:**

**Solution**

Using the launch/core/urdf.launch listed here: https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at/blob/1ac3f552a487495c049333fa5c51bc37c8b5dd75/launch/core/urdf.launch on git. A user needs to Look at line 6:  This puts a prefix on published transforms from this node. Removing it or changing value to "", takes out undesired "Pioneer3AT".

A possible second fix, modify xacro file listed here: https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at/blob/1ac3f552a487495c049333fa5c51bc37c8b5dd75/urdf/pioneer3at.xacro  on line 12, chassis link already has Pioneer3AT in its name. Try renaming it just to "base_link" after cloning the ros-pioneer3at repo to the workspace and modify it there. I will update with second fix for a cleaner solution provided by Gustavo Adolfo Velasco Hernández.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189495/tf-listener-cant-look-up-transform-frame/) by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-08**:
Not sure if syntax is same for python, but pulled from the tf listener tutorial: "The time at which we want to transform. Providing ros::Time(0) will just get us the latest available transform." Try doing at time 0 so you dont have a delay and just grab the latest transform. Maybe thatll help

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-08**:
I used `now = rospy.Time(0)` in my first bit of code above, from the tf listener tutorial, throwing back the first error. Then followed the tf time tutorial, producing the second bit of code. `rospy.Time.now()` does not accept arguments. Retried `rospy.Time(0)` in second bit code. Same error.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-08**:
once everything is running, run roswtf and tell me if it gives you any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the tf python api docs [here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#transformlistener) for waitForTransform, it tells you "*Waits for the given transformation to become available. If the timeout occurs before the transformation becomes available, raises tf.Exception.*" Common thing alot of people have is that there is a delay in the broadcasted tf messages being sent somewhere in your tf tree. Could that somehow be a possibilty in your case?

---

**EDIT:**
With the pictures that you have posted, it shows that you have two base_link frame:

- Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link
- Pioneer3AT/base_link

'Pioneer3AT_Gazebo' is broadcasting a transform from Pioneer3AT/odom --> **Pioneer3AT/base_link** (the tf tree on the right side of the image), but all of your wheels, sensors, top plate, axels, etc. are all being transformed into the frame **Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link**. This is where your problem is.

You can simply fix this by changing your Pioneer3AT_tf_broadcaster node to publish a transform from your sonars, axels, and top plate to frame id Pioneer3AT/base_link *instead* of Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link.

Should look something like this for the Pioneer3AT/front_sonar --> Pioneer3AT/base_link:

```
broadcaster.sendTransform(
            tf::StampedTransform(tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(x, y, z, w), tf::Vector3(x, y, z)),
            ros::Time::now(),"Pioneer3AT/base_link", "Pioneer3AT/front_sonar"));
```

Hope that fixes it. Take out the Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link frame, switch it with Pioneer3AT/base_link, and your tf tree should be connected and you should be able to lookup the transform.

---

**EDIT2:**

As of right now, since you neither you nor I can find the tf broadcaster, the /Pioneer3AT/base_link and /Pioneer3AT/odom frames can be ignored. They will just be frames in our system (for now), so try to make your own broadcaster node that broadcasts just the transform from /Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link --> Pioneer3AT/odom.

Make sure you change the base_link frame in the Pioneer3AT core launch file [here](https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at/blob/master/launch/core/gazebo.launch) to "Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link". Leave all your other sensor frames how you had them originally (if you modified them).

This is just a temporary hack just so we can get this working.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-08**:
Sometimes if your node's topic subscriber is receiving to many message, and your que size is fairly large, this can also cause the problem since the que will cause those messages to be delayed.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-08**:
I run `tf tf_echo /Pioneer3AT/map /Pioneer3AT/base_link` and compute exact data needed. Have also tried increasing `rospy.Duration()` to longer times, still no change.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-08**:
tf_echo only displays you the information between those two frames, so if there is a lag it wont matter. Its just like rostopic echo. Can you post a picture of your transform tree? rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree. It will show us alot of detail about all your frames.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-08**:
Here is an online link of pic:

[link text](http://postimg.org/image/pw5zno2y1/09c69eda/)

and here

[link text](http://postimg.org/image/x051z8cn9/af4573f9/)

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-08**:
I have provided a solution below. You helped me work through the problem in knowing where to search, thanks!! I have yet to try your last solution, I will give it a try when I have the chance.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-08**:
Wait, so you actually want to have two separate tress? And then just lookup the transform between then? If thats the case then sorry i wouldve formulated my answer differently.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-08**:
Not at all. This stack is from here: [link text](https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at) i.e. not built by me. The easiest fix for me was my fix. I will try your fix, and update soon. Just need to know where to make the change of `Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link` frame. Thanks.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-11**:
Tried locating the Pioneer3AT_tf_broadcaster node for edit, trying to combine the two trees as you have described. Could not find under the gitHub location here: [link text](https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at)

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-13**:
You are awesome! Thanks for all the help. I edited the file [link text](https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at/blob/master/launch/core/gazebo.launch), replacing in line 10. /Pioneer3AT/base_link with /Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-13**:
Also edited [link text](https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at/blob/1ac3f552a487495c049333fa5c51bc37c8b5dd75/scripts/tf_from_pose), replacing in line 17. /Pioneer3AT/base_link with /Pioneer3AT/Pioneer3AT/base_link. The result is one single tree, and no need to write a broadcaster node.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-13**:
Glad to help :)